# What is the total amount of rep in sff.SE?

Tags: discussion, reputation

The title says it all.

Is it possible to retrieve this information from a database command?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is a [quick query in data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/371333/total-reputation-for-all-users-on-site).

```
select sum(reputation) as total_rep
from users
```

For our site, it returns **11803197** (as of Dec 2017)

Comment: @Valorum I'm ded at Buffy's hat!

Comment: Top 16 users hold more than 17% of all rep. It is worse than what Bernie Sanders said.

Answer (score 9):

This should be very easy to do with a simple SEDE query that just sums the reputation of all users. Using [such a query](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/371338) (and considering the usual weekly update frequency of the data explorer) this reputation sum would be **6,317,380** at the time of answering.

Comment: This is not changing.   Why isn't the view live?   How often does the data it's querying change?

Comment: @ThePopMachine I'm not totally sure, but I think SEDE runs off a different database than the sites do; if so, copying that much data is a *huge* operation

Comment: @ThePopMachine from [the faq](http://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq): How often is the Stack Exchange Data Explorer updated? The data is updated early every Sunday morning around 3:00 UTC.